# Making Table With List Of JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel

I need to a table in Java application. First I used to a Object of class `JTable` but my table has a lot of features and at now I try to use a list of `JPanel` components instead a table.

How can I make a table with a list of panels?

Comment: Please add information: what does this list contain ? how should it look like ? Also you may want to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You display each piece of data in a separate column of the table, not on a JPanel.

Comment: Every jPanel contains  a row of my table . and list makes rows of table in together.  @c0der

Comment: JTable has low speed and used for simple job. but I need to a special type of table and a way for making table is list of jPanels that every panel contains a row of my table. @camickr

Comment: JTable is NOT low speed. It is faster and more efficient than creating multiple panels with multiple components. It is simpler because you also don't need to create your own custom component. In any case for a "simple" job you will never notice a difference between using a JTable and a panel with multiple child panels.

Comment: `but I need to a special type of table` - we have no idea what that means. We don't know what is special so we can't suggest how you might implement this. The basic approach is to create a parent panel that uses a vertical BoxLayout. Then you create child panels with your compnents and add each child panel to the parent panel.

Comment: I need to this features: 1) wrapping line  2) auto resize row with content size (every row has special size) 3) left alignment . when change Render of JTable speed of rendering becomes really slow. And in my table there are 30 rows. If you can write a efficient code. please post your code. @camickr

Comment: 30 rows is nothing. A JTable can renderer thousands of rows easily and efficiently. However a JTable is designed to show data in a  fixed row/column format. If you have different requirements, then you need to use a different solution. I have already given you the suggestion on how to use panels. We still don't have enough information to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: when Render of my table was a JLabel and I used defult Render everything was Ok and number of rows was upper than 30 but when change Render to a class that extends of a JTextArea for wrapping line speed of rendering of JTable was slow. I used to html code for JLabel Render but my problem didn'n solve... @camickr
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588941/wrap-line-in-jtable-and-high-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a table composed of `JPanel`s containing `JTextArea` , start with something like:

```
JPanel table = new JPanel();
table.setLayout(new BoxLayout(table, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
    table.add(getRow(numberOfColumns));
}
```

where `getRow` is defined by

```
private Component getRow(int numberOfColumns) {

    JPanel row = new JPanel();
    //use GridLayout if you want equally spaced columns 
    row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numberOfColumns; colIndex++) {
        row.add(getCell());
    }
    return row;
}
```

and `getCell`

```
private Component getCell() {
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("Add text");
    ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    return ta;
}
```

However, the recommended way is to use a `JTable` and attempt to solve the issues you described in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588941/wrap-line-in-jtable-and-high-speed).

Comment: "However, the recommended way is to use a JTable and attempt to solve the issues you described in a previous post."  my previous post changed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806517/wrapping-line-right-align-auto-resize-row-height-in-jtable

Comment: Thanks. but it has a small problem and it is direction of table that solved easily. @c0der

Comment: "direction of table" ? What do you mean ?

Comment: sorry to bother you @c0der, but I need your help. Please join for a few minutes: https://discord.gg/ehGJ27

Comment: @esQmo_ no bother at all. Glad to be of help if I can. Please ask on SO.

Comment: I get down-voted each time, it's so discouraging... @c0der

Comment: [Doesn't look that bad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5374691/esqmo), anyway its part of life here. You can always delete bad posts.

Comment: " "direction of table" ? What do you mean ?" I was changed `row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` to `row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));` . After changed location of rows and location of columns.

Comment: I don't see why it is a problem as you wrote. It is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have a another problem, I need to apply percentage percent to columns... Can you help me?

Comment: I can try. Post a new question ( mcve !) and post a link as comment here

Comment: My friends go to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879830/making-table-with-list-of-jpanels-with-applying-percentage-size-columns