# Making Table With List Of JPanels ( With Applying Percentage Size Columns )

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In this post [Making Table With List Of JPanels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797852/making-table-with-list-of-jpanels) I can make a Table with lists of panel. And this table has many features but I need a new feature and it is applying percentage columns. It means I like to width of all columns not equals and with an array of floats determines.
This is my class table :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

public class PanelTable extends JPanel {
    private String data[][];
    private String columns[];
    private int numberOfRows;
    private int numberOfColumns;
    private JTextArea[] header;
    private JTextArea[][] cell;

    public PanelTable(String data[][], String columns[]) {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        this.data = data;
        this.columns = columns;


        numberOfRows = data.length;
        numberOfColumns = columns.length;

        makeHeader();
        makeCells();
    }

    public void makeCells() {
        cell = new JTextArea[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
            add(getRow(numberOfColumns, rowIndex));
        }
    }

    public void makeHeader() {
        header = new JTextArea[numberOfColumns];


        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            ta.setBackground(new Color(57, 77, 112));
            ta.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ta.setText(columns[columnIndex]);
            ta.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 25));
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            header[columnIndex] = ta;
        }

        JPanel rowHeader = new JPanel();
        rowHeader.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rowHeader, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
            rowHeader.add(header[i]);
        }
        add(rowHeader);
    }


    public Component getRow(int numberOfColumns, int rowIndex) {

        JPanel row = new JPanel();
        //use GridLayout if you want equally spaced columns
        row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
            row.add(getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex));
        }
        return row;
    }

    public Component getCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (cell[rowIndex][columnIndex] == null) {
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            ta.setSize(50, ta.getHeight());

            ta.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            ta.setText(data[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
            ta.setFont(new Font("Bmitra", Font.BOLD, 15));

            cell[rowIndex][columnIndex] = ta;
        }

        return cell[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

}
```

and this is a gui example for testing :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private PanelTable table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public GUI(){
        super("Bank Table");
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPanel);
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String[][] data= new String[][]{{"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/01"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/02"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/03"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/04"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/05"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/06"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/07"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/08"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/09"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/10"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/11"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/12"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/13"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/14"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/15"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/16"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/17"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/18"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/19"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/20"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/21"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/22"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","3800ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd0000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/23"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/24"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/25"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/26"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/15"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/16"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/17"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/18"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/19"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/20"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/21"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/22"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","3800ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd0000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/23"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/24"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/25"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/26"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/15"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/16"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/17"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/18"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/19"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/20"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/21"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/22"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","3800ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd0000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/23"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/24"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/25"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/26"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/15"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/16"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/17"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/18"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/19"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/20"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/21"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","380dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd00000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/22"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","3800ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd0000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/23"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/24"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/25"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/26"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/27"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/28"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/29"},
                {"0212670003009", "ص 318", "77081634","38000000","0","331142","2102","وصول چک","08:56:46","1397/05/30"}};


        String[] columns= new String[]{"ستون ۲", "ستون ۱", "ستون ۱۰","ستون ۹","ستون ۸","ستون ۷","ستون ۶","ستون ۵","ستون ۴","ستون ۳"};
        PanelTable table = new PanelTable(data,columns);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);

        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        GUI gui =new GUI();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please make it [mcve] by adding  test data and `JFarme`

Comment: @c0der I add a GUI class for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:
First create an array of width size. for example :

```
 final int[] columnsWidth = { 300, 100, 50, 300, 50 };
```

then on your method makeHeader and getCell, where you are setting all the attributes of text area, set preferred size also. See the code below. This should give you the width based on the size array.

```
ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(columnsWidth[columnIndex], ta.getHeight()));
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Below is the complete code:
For GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private PanelTable2 table;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public GUI(){
        super("Bank Table");
        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPanel);
        contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final String[] columns = { "Big Column", "Serodys", "Ramírez", "Entrada", "MercaSur" };


        final String[][] data = {{"2323", "Hundreds","2323", "Hundreds","2323"},{"2323", "Hundreds","2323", "Hundreds","2323"}}; 
        // final PanelTable22 panel = new PanelTable22(data, columns);

        System.out.println("Hey");
        PanelTable2 table = new PanelTable2(data,columns);
        System.out.println("!!!");

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(50);

        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        GUI gui =new GUI();
    }


}
```

For Table Model:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PanelTable2 extends JPanel {
    private String data[][];
    private String columns[];
    private int numberOfRows;
    private int numberOfColumns;
    private JTextArea[] header;
    private JTextArea[][] cell;
    final int[] columnsWidth = { 300, 100, 50, 300, 50 };


    public PanelTable2(String data[][], String columns[]) {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        this.data = data;
        this.columns = columns;


        numberOfRows = data.length;
        numberOfColumns = columns.length;

        makeHeader();
        makeCells();
    }

    public void makeCells() {
        cell = new JTextArea[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numberOfRows; rowIndex++) {
            add(getRow(numberOfColumns, rowIndex));
        }
    }

    public void makeHeader() {
        header = new JTextArea[numberOfColumns];


        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT); 
            ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(columnsWidth[columnIndex], ta.getHeight())); 
            ta.setBackground(new Color(57, 77, 112));
            ta.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            ta.setText(columns[columnIndex]);
            ta.setFont(new Font("Calibri Light", Font.BOLD, 25));
            ta.setLineWrap(true);

            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setEditable(false);
            header[columnIndex] = ta;
        }

        JPanel rowHeader = new JPanel();
        rowHeader.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rowHeader, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
            rowHeader.add(header[i]);
        }
        add(rowHeader);
    }


    public Component getRow(int numberOfColumns, int rowIndex) {

        JPanel row = new JPanel();
        //use GridLayout if you want equally spaced columns
        row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
            row.add(getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex));
        }
        return row;
    }

    public Component getCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (cell[rowIndex][columnIndex] == null) {
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setEditable(false);

            ta.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            ta.setText(data[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
            ta.setFont(new Font("Bmitra", Font.BOLD, 15));
            ta.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(columnsWidth[columnIndex], ta.getHeight())); 

            cell[rowIndex][columnIndex] = ta;
        }

        return cell[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but I wrote this code in before and I try it new time but does **not** work

Comment: I see. I took your code and it worked with the change I had posted. Not sure why it is not working at your end.. The above array is just for 5 columns data that I have tested for. are you getting any error or it is just not changing the width.

Comment: I change your array size to prefer size (10) but It is just not changing. please get me completer code to me. perhaps I put your code to wrong place.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I test your gui and this is Ok however in my application does not work ; perhaps it has another problem.

Comment: I wish I could solve your actual problem also. I will give it a try. For percentage thing, you can have an array of percentage and calculate the actual width size based on percentage value and the full width size of header.

Comment: actual problem when occurred that I change number of rows to large number and height size get into trouble however width size change well

Answer (score 0):

The key are these rows :

```
//use GridLayout if you want equally spaced columns
row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

to apply constrains to columns you can use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead of `BoxLayout`.

Here is a very basic mcve of using `GridBagLayout`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class PanelTable2 extends JPanel {

    public PanelTable2() {

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        add(getRow());
    }

    Component getRow() {

        int[] percent =  {10,40,50};

        JPanel row = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        row.setLayout(layout);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        for (int i= 0; i < percent.length; i++) {
            gbc.gridy = 0 ; gbc.gridx = i;
            gbc.weightx = percent[i];
            Component component =  getCell();
            row.add(component, gbc);
        }
        return row;
    }

    Component getCell() {

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(4,11);
        ta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        ta.setFont(new Font("Bmitra", Font.BOLD, 15));
        return ta;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(new PanelTable2());
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note that the mcve should not represent your application. It should be a simple representation of the problem.
`GridBagLayout` is by no means the only option. There are other alternatives you can explore like [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).

Comment: I use your code in between my application but does not work. Even when test your code and type in its cells percentage make problem...

Comment: It is not meant to be used in your code as is. It is meant to point you to the write direction and show you  what I think you should learn. This site is not "code writing service" but a place where you can hope for guidance.

Comment: I see that you say friend; But your answer very simple and  I am beginner so I can not solve them .please help me...

Comment: That is what I try to do. Run the code posted, adapt it to your needs and if needed ask specific questions about it.

Comment: I tested your code with `.setText` to `ta` and percentage did not apply. This show your code does not satisfied key feature in this question.

Comment: This does not sound like a question to me, but more like a complaint.  I do not not see this "key feature" in the question. I am sorry that I could not help and hope you'll get better answers.

Comment: I do not like bother you... **Key feature** in this question is **Applying Percentage Size**. Do not accept it?